# How to Apply Sharepoint Permissions on List items Columns

Tags: 2013, list

I have a sharepoint list which basically has two group of users:

Group1
Group2

Group1 has full control on a list

Group2 has limited access:
  Group 2 can read only list item except for few column which they can make changes

List: XYZ

List Columns:
field1,Field2,field3,field4

Out of these Fields when user is group2 is logged in and open a list item and try to edit the list item. I would only want to allow them to edit field3 and field4.

Can such thing be done out of the box, if we have any other ways to do it(i.e quick Jquery) how do we achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

**Can such thing be done out of the box ?**

No, but you can use [info wise](http://www.infowisesolutions.com/products.aspx)

**if we have any other ways to do it(i.e quick Jquery) how do we achieve that?**

You can do this with SPServices

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/test/Script/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/test/Script/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$().SPServices({
operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
async: false,
completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
var xml = xData.responseXML.xml;
if(xml.search('SharePoint Group') != -1)
{

$('nobr:contains("TestColumn")').closest('tr').hide();

}
}
});
});
</script>
```

For more details check [SHAREPOINT – USE JQUERY TO HIDE COLUMNS BASED ON A USERS GROUP MEMBERSHIP](https://theezitguy.wordpress.com/2014/10/01/sharepoint-use-jquery-to-hide-columns-based-on-a-users-group-membership/)

Comment: Excellent i will try this jquery and get back to you. Thank you for your quick responce.

Answer (score 0):

Although as @M.Qassas mentioned, there is no out of the box functionality to lock down column (field) level permissions. You could work around this issue by having seperate lists, with seperate permissions, and utilising a lookup column. Note that certain data types are not compatible with lookups (Person or Group, for instance).

Example:

List A - Permissions (Group 1, Group 2)
Column x
Column y
Column z (lookup)

List B - Permissions (Group 1)
Column z

Only users in Group 1 would be able to see the data in Column z, when looking at List A.

Hope this helps

Comment: George, that sounds great, but i dont have flexibility to create multiple lists at this point. Lists are already been created, so are views.